# How does one determine which page is currently being edited using WordPress inbuilt functionality?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I have written a module into my WordPress theme, its overly complicated and irrelevant.

I need to include a block of code and want a reliable way to determine if the user is currently editing specific pages.

Essentially, I want the equivalent of the front-end check:

```
if (is_front_page()) {
```

But, for when on the editor pages.

It is required to be able to target pages that are not given special names like front-page / shop-page too. So I may need to target by post ID.

What is the cleanest way to perform this check?

I have tried the function above, along with:

```
$screen = get_current_screen();
```

However, this forces a critical error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in ... points to line.
```

A couple other methods have also been attempted, I just note a few. I thought I would be able to get one to work but none seem to do the trick. Please can someone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
Adding example snippet

---

```
// This creates the fatal error.
// $screen = get_current_screen();
// var_dump($screen);

// This is for the front-end 
// if (is_front_page()) {

// global $pagenow;
// var_dump($pagenow);
// if ($pagenow == 'post.php') {
// This returns string(8) "post.php" which is not descript enough.

// This is front-end
// global $post;
// $post_id = $post->ID;
// Post ID 3887 is Home

if ($post_id == '3887') {

    echo 'hello!';

    require_once('inc/overlays/page-template/fc-front-page.php');
    
} else {

    echo 'Well that did not work!';

}
```

The reason I am doing this is irrelevant, I simply want to include a file in a different folder, the file called will be different depending on which page is currently being edited!

Comment: What critical error are you seeing exactly?

Comment: @cabrerahector - updated question for you :)

Comment: Ah, I don't think you normally have access to admin functions such as [get_current_screen()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/) from your theme unless you use specific hooks in your theme, like [admin_init](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_init/) for example.

Comment: With that said, if you want us to be of more help than this then please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (and explain why you're doing all this) so we can share more suggestions.

Comment: Added that info for you :) I like the admin_init, however I still require knowledge on how to determine which page is currently being edited.

Answer (score 0):

[`get_current_screen()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/) is only valid on admin pages.

The [`WP_Screen`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/) object is set after the [`admin_init`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init) action hook via the [`current_screen`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/current_screen/) action hook. You can refer to the [Plugin API/Action Reference and the Actions Run During a Typical Request](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) for the firing hook sequence.

To make sure the [`WP_Screen`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_screen/) object is firing, you can use the following function. It will output the screen object as a html commentary on admin pages that support it.

```php
add_action( 'current_screen', 'print_r_get_current_screen' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'print_r_get_current_screen' ) ) {

    function print_r_get_current_screen() {

        echo PHP_EOL . '<!--' . PHP_EOL;
        print_r( get_current_screen() );
        echo PHP_EOL . '-->' . PHP_EOL;

    };

};
```

But I don't think using the current screen will help you in achieving what you're trying to do.

You can use `get_option( 'page_on_front' );` to get the id of the front page.

```
add_action( 'init', 'print_r_get_option_page_on_front' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'print_r_get_option_page_on_front' ) ) {

    function print_r_get_option_page_on_front() {

        echo PHP_EOL . '<!--' . PHP_EOL;
        print_r( get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ); //... 0 if undefined, page ID if defined
        echo PHP_EOL . '-->' . PHP_EOL;

    };

};
```

For woocommerce I'm pretty sure you can use `woocommerce_get_page_id( 'shop' )`.

Comment: Appreciate the interest. I can't use these though, unless you can show me how!